# Which man page describes the process of a computer turning on?

Tags: linux, boot, man

A few years ago I recall using the terminal and reading a tutorial in the Linux manual (using `man`) on how a computer worked after it was turned on. It walked you through the whole process explaining the role of the BIOS, ROM, RAM and OS on this process.

Which page was this, if any? How can I read it again?

Comment: @SatoKatsura It's better to ask and risk having one's question closed than to be forever wondering.

Comment: Thank you all, Kusalananda's answer is what I'm looking for. And a big apology to everybody but since english is not my native language it was hard to remember this simple word "boot" that it would saved everyone's time on this topic. Off I go to continue surfing through man

Comment: @juliotv It's "short" for bootstrapping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping

Comment: It will include things other than just the boot process, but you might want to take at *How Linux Works - What Every Superuser Should Know* by Brian Ward

Comment: @JBentley thanks, will definitely look into that book

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as I don't think it's off-topic. Requests for general learning materials are off-topic but not requests for "official documentation". My (personal) opinion is that the on-line manuals (as read with `man`) constitutes the "official documentation" on a system.

Comment: `man 7 boot` sounds like what you need

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're thinking of the [`boot(7)` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/boot.7.html) (`man 7 boot`) and/or the [`bootup(7)` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootup.7.html) (`man 7 bootup`).  Those are the manuals I can think of on (Ubuntu) Linux that best fits your description.

These manuals are available on the web (see links above), but the definite text is what's available on the system that you are using. If a web-based manual says one thing but the manual on your system says another thing, then the manual on your system is the more correct one for you. This goes for all manuals.

See also the "See also" section in those manuals.

This other question may also be of interest:  [How does the Linux or Unix " / " get mounted during bootup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338150/how-does-the-linux-or-unix-get-mounted-during-bootup)

For a non-Linux take on the boot process, the OpenBSD [first-stage system bootstrap (`biosboot(8)`)](http://man.openbsd.org/biosboot.8) and [second-stage bootstrap (`boot(8)`)](http://man.openbsd.org/boot.8) manuals, followed by [`rc(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/rc.8), may be interesting.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to help OP understand how you knew to look at that particular manpage? I think that is important because many linux beginners learn "read the manpage" but for anything other than `man the-command-i-want-to-use` it isn't immediately obvious how to find the table of contents or index of man pages to find the right one to read.

Comment: @Freiheit I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't anything more to it than having remembered that that particular man page is the one with the relevant content. There's no ToC or index of man pages. There is the `apropos` command which searches man pages, and most standard ones are online and searchable by Google, but that doesn't always get you to the page you want.

Comment: @David that depends on the tool you use; `xman` for example does provide a table of contents for each section (basically, it lists all the manpages in the section — it could be better though, it only gives the manpages’ short names, not their full name which includes a short description).

Comment: @Freiheit On many systems there's an `intro` manual for each section. These often point to further manuals or gives a summary of relevant information not specific to one sub-section.  See for example `man 1 intro`, `man 2 intro` etc.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like boot(7) or bootup(7). ie `man 7 bootup`

You can, incidentally, search the manual via `man -k <keyword>` or the equivalent but more stylish apropos command.